# Is there a way to have child classes omit their parents' unneccessary members?

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++17

In the following example ([coliru link](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1cf17714260ea19)) there are 2 child classes `Child_pub` and `Child_pro`, who are basically the same, except they inherit from different parent classes:

- The first parent, `Parent_priv` has a `private` `int` member `v`,
- the second parent, `Parent_prot` has a `protected` `int` member `v`.

A class, which inherits from `Parent_prot` has access to that `int` member `v`, whereas a class which inherits from `Parent_priv` hasn't, but still it carries its bulk.

**So my question is:** Even if that `private` `v` has no effect on the child class whatsoever, why can't it be optimized away from the child by the compiler?
Why can't my example print `4` for `sizeof` in the second case? Which C++ law forbids that?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Parent_priv {
    private: int v;
};

class Parent_prot {
    protected: int v;
};

class Child_priv final : public Parent_priv {
    int x;
};

class Child_prot final : public Parent_prot {
    int x;
};

int main() {
    Child_prot child_prot;
    Child_priv child_priv;
    std::cout << "sizeof(child_prot) = " << sizeof(child_prot) << '\n'; // prints 8 on my system
    std::cout << "sizeof(child_priv) = " << sizeof(child_priv) << '\n'; // also 8
}
```

**Is there a way to make the compiler** (we use both, GCC an Clang) **optimize** `child_priv` **to have** `sizeof` **4?**

Of course there is more to those parent classes in our real code, so *not inheriting* would not be an option.

---

**Context:** In our code we're sending tons of child classes like that around over TCP, which carry unneccessary bulk from their parents, using a serialization routine, which depends on `sizeof`. We'd have to implement custom serialization for all these child classes, manually omitting unneeded member variables, which we don't feel like apparently.

- Yes, we're already zipping the network packages using zlib.
- And no, we can't use UDP instead of TCP.

Comment: You use two different compilers, and yet rely on the implementation defined size and padding of the structures for compatibilty? You are bold.

Comment: @Ivella Thank you for pointing that out. Clang is not used for production, it sometimes issues more and more helpful warnings during compilation.

Comment: The short answer is "no".   When using a base polymorphically (e.g. a pointer to a base class that points at an instance of a derived class) the compiler needs to assume that the "base part" is common in all derived classes.   If the compiler was somehow able to optimise out members of a base class for some particular derived classes and not others, it would break that assumption.   Also, even if a derived class doesn't directly use members of the base class, there is a fair chance that member functions of the base class (however called) WILL use private members of the base.

Comment: custom serialization sounds like a good idea

Comment: @Jabberwocky - The question is clearly asked because they don't *want* to do custom serialization - so they're hoping a compiler switch or two will make it happen by magic.   They're whistling.

Comment: @Peter yes I know, but it's still a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

**No, you can't do that, for good reason**

> A class, which inherits from Parent_prot has access to that int member v, whereas a class which inherits from Parent_priv hasn't, but still it carries its bulk.

`Child_priv` doesn't have direct access to `Parent_priv::v`, but presumably member functions or friends of `Parent_priv` use it.

If nothing is using `Parent_priv::v`, why is it declared in the first place?

How should a compiler distinguish between data members that you can't be bothered to remove, and data members that I've added to make padding explicit?

Comment: _If nothing is using Parent_priv::v, why is it declared in the first place?_ - As code grows, sometimes new requirements don't fit old inheritance hierachies anymore. And refactoring that is a lot of work, that most if not all bosses deem unneccessary.

Comment: And how would you (make the compiler?) prove that the variable actually _isn't_ used anywhere?

Comment: @codeling: As all the other "remove" optimizations? The compiler knows which objects are accessed and which not. From the technical point of view it can remove unused data from class. And doing this did not violate the standards. But I did not know any compiler which is currently optimizing data out of structs...

Comment: @Klaus not necessarily the compiler knows. The linker might know, but not the compiler. For most classes seen from a compilation unit, the compiler doesn't know the body of those functions, so it can't know if a private variable is used or not. The compiiler only knows the body of the function on the .cpp file that implements that class, but most are seen from includes headers only,

Comment: @lvella: This is nothing special to all optimizations. All as inline funcs or compiled with LTO. The linker itself can't do anything after that, because data access offsets are already located in this stage ( for typical implementations ).

Comment: @Klaus: LTO (link time optimization) is precisely why I said "The linker might know, but not the compiler."

Comment: @nada ", that most if not all bosses deem unneccessary." is not true in my experience. Bosses do understand that software = code and that code needs to be maintained. If they didnt understand they would fail soon. If your boss doesnt understand, either convince him or look for some other place ;)

Comment: @lvella: NO, not the linker... LTO is link TIME and not the linker. :-) Link stage is to late, as offsets to base address is not longer changeable ( in current implementations )

Comment: @Klaus You are just juggling with semantics now... badly. Even if LTO was not triggered inside the program called "the linker" (it does, that alone makes my statement correct), something can not happen at "link time" if linking is not what is happening at the time.

Comment: @lvella: "something can not happen at "link time" if linking is not what is happening at the time" you are right, it is after all sources are parsed. Now all the sources will be compiled "at once" after that the link stage follows. LTO is pre link!

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that. If you don't want the filds from the base class, your only option is to not inherit.

Even if the compiler would usually optimize out the unused fields in some cirscumstances, when you use `sizeof` the compiler is conservative and returns the full size.

Comment: It probably does not apply to OP's case, but it brings an interesting question: there might be some cases where te compiler can prove there is no way a variable is ever used, I.e. all functions defined inside the scope of the class, the variable is private, and no function touches it. Would the language specification allow the compiler to supress that variable on the calculated size?

Comment: clang has warning for unused private member. It might miss some cases, but can detect some. [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f36f55c0ea2cb7b8)